# Sticky items, that follow divs

Tags: jquery, scroll

Okey, the problem. I want, that this (see demo link below) dark gray box (which will be a placeholder for image) appears and scrolls along, while user is reading long post, but when user reaches to next article, this previous box just holds there, where it is, and next box start to scroll along, and so on.

Now, I could manage that first box somehow slides along, but all these boxes, which are in this html, slides too.

All, what I need, is little jquery enhancement, to make it work.

Here is that, what I've made till now http://jsfiddle.net/yG5Gy/

As well as, basic javascript it self:

```
$(".content").bind("scroll", function() {
    if ($(".content").scrollTop() + 275 <= $(".post_text").height()) {
        $(".post_img").css("top", $(".content").scrollTop());
    }
});​
```

Thanks,

/Rob

Comment: Hello Rob, Can you please post the applicable code in the question as well as the demo link. Always remember that jsFiddle is not associated with StackOverflow and if it ever does decide to shut down your question will no longer be useful to the community.

Answer (score 0):

The key to your issue is that you're using class selectors with multiple results. You'll need to use the each method to manipulate each post individually:

```
$("li.entry").each(function(){
    // This will select only the image within the currently looped entry div
    $(this).find(".post_img");
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the idea, but I don't know, how to use it. I always have problems understanding how this .each() is working...

Comment: When you use $(".entry"), you get a collection of entry items. Anything you deal with inside the function will not be able to access the individual elements inside any particular entry class item. By using .each(), you loop through each matched element, which is available as the variable $(this).

Comment: Okey, I will try to figure it out, but if not, I'll return for help :)

Comment: Well, I tried, but now I can make so, that every boxes are moving down in once:
[see here](http://pastebin.com/xn9Y203e) but still, this is not what I wanted